# I'm trying to create a virtual environment in Python 3 but can't get it set up

Tags: python, windows

So basically to create the virtual environment I'm running:

$ virtualenv -p python3 ve

But when I run this I get: "The path python3 (from --python=python3) does not exist"

So I tried to do a mkdir ve and that doesn't work either. I'm not very familiar with virtual environments so I've tried a bunch of things and nothing seems to work. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What does `which python3` give you?

Comment: just tried and I'm getting:

"'which' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: Then you are using significantly less linux than I assumed. It wouldn't hurt adding the windows tag to this question to make that more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that python3 is not on your path. You can test that with ...

```
python3 --version
```

If you get an error your virtualenv creation will fail as well.

Just use the full path of your python executable with the -p flag i.e.:

```
virtualenv -p /some_odd_location/bin/python3 env
```

In Windows this will be probably

```
virtualenv -p C:\python3\bin\python3.exe env (I will verify tomorrow)
```

And of course make sure python3 is installed in the first place.

Alternatively, you can also symlink your python executable in /usr/bin but that will affect the global settings.

Virtual environments are not much more than alternative path settings in the shell where they are activated plus a clean python installation in the folder that you create by invoking virtualenv.

Comment: `python3 --version` returns:
'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

but

`python --version` returns:
Python 3.6.1 :: Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)

I did have Python 2 installed a while back so does this mean that my Command Prompt is still referencing the older version? Should I just uninstall Python 2 altogether and start fresh? I also have Anaconda (if that makes a difference).

Comment: This means Python 3 is on your path. In that case simply calling virtualenv should create a virtual environment using Python 3.6.1. The executable for python 3 is still called 'python'. You might symlink it as python3 if you like to have both versions on hand. Your python 3 install might have overwritten the symlink to Python 2.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was able to run `virtualenv -p LOCATION ve` successfully to create a virtual environment. 

But now the issue is getting activated. I tried `source ve/bin/activate` and `LOCATION ve/bin/activate` and looked around the site for answer but couldn't find anything. Any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: Did you look into the ve folder? What is there?

Comment: Just checked the ve folder and there's:

Include (folder)
Lib (folder)
Scripts(folder)
tcl (folder)
pip-selfcheck.json

Comment: Also, I just ran `ve\Scripts\activate.bat` and it returns `(ve) C:\Users\David>` Does that mean that it's all set up correctly and ready to go?

Comment: Yes, if you are on Windows you have to run ve\Scripts\activate.bat. Sorry for assuming you were on Linux or OSX. You are all good now.

Answer (score 1):

I usually create virtual environments with
`python3 -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment` (here's the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)

To be able to do this you need to have installed python 3 globally.

Also if you want to use that environment you may need to activate it:

`source /path/to/new/virtual/environment/bin/activate`

These commands work on Unix based systems.

Comment: Thanks this is helpful. But when I use 

`python3 -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment`

I get **python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

I'm using Python 3 so not sure what's going on here

Comment: Which Operative System do you use?

Comment: I'm on Windows 10

Comment: Again, python is not on your current path. You have two options. Set the PATH variable or find the executable and provide as argument to virtualenv.